# Detecting VPN connection in macOS (sandboxed)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, vpn

I am trying to detect whether a VPN connection is active in macOS from within a sandboxed application, but am having a hard time finding a common solution for various VPN services. Currently, I am using 2 approaches (see below), but these methods don't appear to be reliable for all VPN services/clients.

The below methods work great for the Cisco AnyConnect client and my VPN service, but for other VPN clients/services, such as Viscosity (and presumably other OpenVPN clients), these methods simply don't work. When comparing the values from *not-active*-VPN-connection to *active*-VPN-connection, no changes are detected in either DNS servers or the primary service value.

I should also mention that I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16285093/how-to-detect-iphones-vpn-connectivity?rq=1) and don't think it is a good solution for this particular use case. I don't want to assume that for every VPN service out there that is always going to be a host that is *only* available when the VPN connection is active.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

1) Looking at the current DNS servers (taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/zulkis/7eb85c28dd9738f5a824daf0421600a1))

```
- (NSString *)getDNSAddressesCSV
{
    NSMutableArray *addresses = [NSMutableArray new];

    union res_sockaddr_union servers[NI_MAXSERV];

    int serversFound = res_9_getservers(_state, servers, NI_MAXSERV);

    char hostBuffer[NI_MAXHOST];

    for (int i = 0; i < serversFound; i ++)
    {
        union res_sockaddr_union s = servers[i];

        if (s.sin.sin_len > 0)
        {
            if (EXIT_SUCCESS == getnameinfo((struct sockaddr *)&s.sin,  // Pointer to your struct sockaddr
                                            (socklen_t)s.sin.sin_len,   // Size of this struct
                                            (char *)&hostBuffer,        // Pointer to hostname string
                                            sizeof(hostBuffer),         // Size of this string
                                            nil,                        // Pointer to service name string
                                            0,
                                            NI_NUMERICHOST))
            {          // Flags given
                [addresses addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:hostBuffer]];
            }
        }
    }

    return [addresses componentsJoinedByString:@","];
}
```

and 2) Getting the current primary service from [SCDynamicStore](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/scdynamicstore?language=objc) (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512365/programatially-determine-if-cisco-vpn-client-is-connected?rq=1))

```
- (NSString *) getVPNService
{
    SCDynamicStoreRef dynamicStoreDomainState = SCDynamicStoreCreate(NULL,
                                                                     CFSTR("appNameGoesHere"),
                                                                     NULL,
                                                                     NULL);
    if (dynamicStoreDomainState)
    {
        NSString *netIPv4Key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@/%@",
                                kSCDynamicStoreDomainState,
                                kSCCompNetwork,
                                kSCCompGlobal,
                                kSCEntNetIPv4];

        NSMutableDictionary *netIPv4Dictionary = (NSMutableDictionary *) CFBridgingRelease(SCDynamicStoreCopyValue(dynamicStoreDomainState, (CFStringRef)netIPv4Key));

        if (netIPv4Dictionary )
        {
            NSString *primaryService = [netIPv4Dictionary objectForKey:(NSString *)kSCDynamicStorePropNetPrimaryService];

            if (primaryService)
            {
                CFRelease(dynamicStoreDomainState);
                CFRelease((__bridge CFTypeRef)(netIPv4Key));
                return primaryService;
            }
            else
            {
                CFRelease(dynamicStoreDomainState);
                CFRelease((__bridge CFTypeRef)(netIPv4Key));
                return @"";
            }
        }

        CFRelease(dynamicStoreDomainState);
    }

    return @"";
}
```

Comment: @GeneCode - Apple prohibits harvesting user and system data without consent as defined in Data Collection and Storage (https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#data-collection-and-storage). Data collection and storage is not the same as making an observation of networking configuration that is then used to provide a user-expected function within an app.

Answer (score 0):

From Google, look here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/113491

> Apple staff said no such public API exists.

Also from Google, look here: https://superuser.com/questions/577094/how-can-i-tell-if-os-x-is-connected-to-a-vpn-network-from-the-command-line

> That last Apple Script solution might interest you